# В какой программе создаются подобные флаги?

Tags: изображения, adobe

[image: img flag]

Answer (score 1):

Например - 3ds MAX.

http://www.jovdes.com/tutorial/fluttering_flag_3d_max/

http://www.skachat-uroki.ru/2009/01/modeliruem-flag/

Answer (score 0):

3ds MAX для 3д моделирования, больше для геймдева. 
для подобной анимации лучше подойдет adobe after effects